# what does cluster which made by MFCCs mean?

Tags: speech-recognition, k-means, gaussian, mfcc

I make a emotion-recognition program  using MFCC + GMM.

Because of android, I use a java package called comirva.

Using this package and emotion-speech DB, I make a GMM in each emotion like angryGMM, happyGMM...

Before I made a GMM, I created a KMeanClustering object, and init cluster number.

As i know. If i init cluster number to 3, set of points will be divide into 3 cluster.

But i'm not sure what does one cluster mean.

Q1)
What does one cluster mean?
Is it just used in pattern matching?

After creating a GMM, I run GMM.EM algoritm using point-list that already had been used once in KMeansClustering.
Q2)
What I wonder is that why same point-list is used in training although GMM is created by this point-list.